# Accessing a single int element from a DataView (List<int>)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I pass a DataView object, which is a list of ints, to a view. I also have a foreach loop on my page, where I would like to do the following:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
    <% if ((ViewData["listOfIDs"] as List<int>).ElementAt(i) == item.ID){
        <p>Display this</p>
    { %>
{ %>
```

I have two problems. First I have to get the iteration number of the foreach loop, without converting it to a for loop. Secondly, I have to write a valid expression in the if statement.

I would gladly use a for loop, but I don't know how to rewrite the lines in the foreach loop, which looks like this:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
<tr>
    <td>
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.project.name) %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name) %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.priority) %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.points) %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Eidt", "Edit", new {  id=item.card_id }) %> |
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new {  id=item.card_id }) %> |
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new {  id=item.card_id }) %>
    </td>
</tr>
<% } %>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Sounds like you are over complicating it. There may be a solution but what I am thinking of won't work if there are duplicate numbers (probably isn't as they are ID's according to your code). Use a for loop and go to bed happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
    <% if ((ViewData["listOfIDs"] as List<int>).ElementAt((ViewData["listOfIDs"] as List<int>).IndexOf(item)) == item.ID){
        <p>Display this</p>
    { %>
{ %>
```

Nasty, slow, unreadable, and easily broken.

```
<% for  (int i=0; i < Model.Count; i++) { %>
<tr>
    <td>
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].project.name) %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].name) %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].priority) %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].points) %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Eidt", "Edit", new {  id=Model[i].card_id }) %> |
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new {  id=Model[i].card_id }) %> |
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new {  id=Model[i].card_id }) %>
    </td>
</tr>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would gladly use a for loop, but since I'm new to this technology I have a hard time transcribing the lines in it. Updated the question with the whole foreach loop.

Comment: @RunoTheDog  I don't get it. It sounds like you know what a for loop does. Did you try the above and it didn't work?

Comment: You should use Razor btw. Much nicer

Comment: The above didn't work, since I have to instantiate an "item" object somewhere.

Comment: Sorry. Replace item with Model

Comment: Accepted a bit too soon? :P